# Monitoring values against conditions

Tags: java, android, performance, design-patterns, monitor

I want to monitor constantly changing values against different conditions.

Example case:
Value: Location (changes every 5 seconds)
Condition: If location.near(Boston) do ...

It seems easy to do for one value and condition, but if there are multpile values and conditions I fear it will cripple the hardware because it will run on Android devices.

Is there a design pattern to help me with this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that a good solution can be a Rule Engine. There are some rule engines that work fine on Android platform, e.g. [Jess](http://herzberg.ca.sandia.gov/).

Another lightweight rule engine available on Java is [Reguloj](https://github.com/sebhoss/reguloj)

Basically, a rule engine is based on a set of rules, each of which consists in a condition and an ation.

[Here](http://www.jessrules.com/guidelines.shtml) you can find more about your choice to use or not a rule engine.

Comment: Thanks, Jess is paid for Android atm but Reguloj looks interesting!

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, Reguloj also seems very simple.